# The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.tablename

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server-explorer

I created a table with the following query in the Server Explorer:

```
CREATE TABLE monitoring
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
[brandname_id] INT NULL, 
[module_id] INT NULL, 
[frequency_id] INT NULL, 
[succ_count] INT NULL, 
[failCalib_count] INT NULL, 
[failWriteFlash_count] INT NULL, 
[failEraseDevice_count] INT NULL, 
[failWriteAVR_count] INT NULL, 
[programmingLocation] INT NULL, 
[dateonly] DATE NULL
)
```

I then deleted the database, this table and attempted to recreate both of them again with the same database name and table query. Upon clicking the 'Update' button in the table designer I get the following message:

```
Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.Id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.brandname_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.module_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.frequency_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.succ_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failCalib_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failWriteFlash_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failEraseDevice_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failWriteAVR_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.programmingLocation.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.dateonly.
SQL71501 :: Default Constraint: [dbo].[CONSTRAINT_NAME] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[monitoring].
SQL71501 :: Default Constraint: [dbo].[CONSTRAINT_NAME] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[monitoring].[dateonly].
SQL71501 :: Primary Key: unnamed constraint on [dbo].[monitoring] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[monitoring].
SQL71501 :: SqlIndexedColumnSpecification: <unnamed> has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[monitoring].[Id].
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.Id.
SQL71501 :: Primary Key: unnamed constraint on [dbo].[monitoring] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[monitoring].
SQL71501 :: SqlIndexedColumnSpecification: <unnamed> has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[monitoring].[Id].
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.brandname_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.module_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.frequency_id.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.succ_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failCalib_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failWriteFlash_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failEraseDevice_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.failWriteAVR_count.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.programmingLocation.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.monitoring.dateonly.
```

I assume some temp files weren't cleared so it thinks the table still exists. Does anybody know of a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're using an EDMX file and a db first approach, have you deleted the old entity from the designer?

Comment: I created a .mdf file (Service-based database) and deleted this file from the Server Explorer menu (via right click -> delete).